# Does War of the Chosen add anything to the tutorial?

Tags: xcom-2, xcom-2-war-of-the-chosen

I'd like to do a blind run of War of the Chosen. I have no more idea of what I will encounter past the [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCOM_2:_War_of_the_Chosen).

I've already played multiple runs of vanilla, so I'm wondering, will I get anything useful out of the tutorial this time around. XCOM: Enemy Within had a neat Meld tutorial; is the same sort of thing present in WotC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty much the same tutorial, most of the content happens after that.

Source: I've played a lot of it. :)

Comment: There is one useful thing you get from the tutorial: Jane Kelly, ranger extraordinaire.  (The tutorial does fail the "don't lose any soldiers" achieve, though.)

Answer (score 3):

War of the Chosen adds a tutorial for the new features- The Lost and the Chosen. It adds introductory missions for the new soldier types, the chosen, and the lost.

This option can be enabled or disabled separately from the main tutorial when starting a new game.

Comment: Probably useful to mention that this occurs as a mission a bit into the game (after Gatecrasher). It's not a change to the original tutorial.