# Where did I get 3 deaths from?

Tags: xcom-2, xcom-2-war-of-the-chosen

I just finished my first WotC game, and there's an interesting anomaly in the ending stats: "3 soldiers killed". I do not remember ever losing a soldier in this game, but it says I lost 3. The world average is apparently 8, which is odd given that I'm on Veteran difficulty.

Some theories:

- It's counting the bonus soldiers left at the end of missions. Possible, but I know that I've never lost any of *these* either. And I've gotten more than 3 of these.
- It's counting the Resistance soldiers in retaliation strikes. 3 sounds like a good number for how many of those were killed throughout my campaign.

So what events are counted by the "soldiers killed" stat, other than an XCOM soldier dying?

Comment: I don't think anyone except for you knows what happened in your game.

Comment: Did you have your tutorial enabled?  The deaths in the tutorial mission count.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer why should that be relevant? I'm asking about the things that this counter counts.

Comment: @lI no I didn't. You were the one who told me to turn it off if I remember correctly. And that's only 2 deaths anyway.

Comment: Then edit your question to ask what counts as a death. As it is, nobody can answer.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer is that presently unclear?

Comment: Considering the question is "Where did I get 3 deaths from?", yeah, I would say so. With the question as it is, it's just inviting guesses instead of facts.

Comment: The question states `So what is it counting?` at the end. Is that unclear?

Comment: Once again, yes. Your entire question is asking to guess why your death counter shows 3, and nobody can answer that. I don't think I can say much more without repeating myself.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer is this good?

Comment: Does it count dead mind controlled aliens? I know the end mission tallies count mind  controlled alien deaths along with the soldiers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The two things included in the *soldiers killed* metric are:

1. KIA members of your squad (not resistance soldiers added via the resistance order, nor the fighters on retaliation strikes).
2. **Mind-controlled enemies**. When a unit under your control dies, it counts under that statistic. Edit from comments: Enemy machines destroyed while under your control also count.

Comment: Hmm… actually, I can't remember using MC ever. My psi operatives didn't see much action, really.

Comment: Possibly the commander's avatar on the final mission?

Comment: That I know I didn't use.

Comment: Ok. At present those are the 2 things I know it counts. Given your experience there might be another, but I'm unaware of it.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Hacking Turrets/Robots also counts as Mind Control

Comment: @Oak The haywire skill, right? But would those units then count as *soldiers killed*...

Comment: @Oak actually, that sounds fairly plausible.

Comment: @RoijanEskor Machines and such are count as soldiers. Soldiers that die while mind controlled count as lost soldiers, which means using Haywire results in them being counted as lost soldiers

Answer (score -3):

You lose some people in the very first tutorial mission.  They show up in the memorial plaque in the bar on the avenger.  They probably count in the total dead statistic.

Comment: First of all, [I didn't have the tutorial on](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/321796/176491); second, only one soldier dies in the tutorial, not the 3 that I had.